# MySQLi weird behaviour - Showing Insertion success but no records in table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a weird issue in my mysql which is happening on a specific table !

I have a DB class as follows...

```
// Class: Database

class Database {

    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $_error = '';

    /*
        SingleTon function to return DB Instance.
    */

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // Constructor
    private function __construct() { 
        global $db_host;
        global $db_username;
        global $db_password;
        global $db_database;
        $this->_connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

        // Error handling
        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            $this->_error = "Failed to conencto to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
        }
    }

    // Get mysqli connection
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->_connection;
    }

}
?>
```

In my Other class where i need db action i do use following on constructor...

```
 $db = Database::getInstance();
 $this->mysql = $db->getConnection();
```

and following that i use $this->mysql->query("INSERT_QUERY") to insert the data. In the end i use $this->mysql->insert_id to see if the insertion has successfull returned id or not... In my execution of insertion i do get successfull auto incremented ID as output. But if i see DB through PHPMyAdmin tool the db is empty ! Even in select query also i do get nothing... but if i keep insert data i do get output of auto incremented value !

More over this happening in just one table. There are few other tables where i do the same insertion action and that does works normal !

All tables are on INNODB Engine.

Just to test i do delete that specific table but still i got same auto incremented value with out error message that table doesn't exist !!! but if i change the db name it throws me error which confirms that the connection points to the same DB.

This is really weird... does anyone faced similar problem ?

Comment: check if you change the auto commit feature from your connection. maybe after closing your connection `rollback` occurred.

Comment: hi wajeeh, thank you for your reply. can you explain a bit more ? do i need to set auto commit 'ON' for the query to work ? actually in my program 3 insertion actions happen on 3 different tables... other 2 table data seems fine and just in one table it behaves weird !

Comment: in this case I do not think this is the problem, without viewing the code we can not help you, sorry.

Comment: @wajeeh - You are right. It starts working after i set $this->mysql->autocommit(true); on constructor of my class. Thank you for the input.

Comment: you are welcome, I will post my answer to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you change the auto commit feature from your connection. maybe after closing your connection a `rollback` occurred.

```
$this->mysql->autocommit(true);
```